# C# Infopath Detect Invalid Signatures

Tags: c#, infopath, infopath2010

I have a bunch of Infopath 2010 forms stored in Sharepoint 2010.  A lot of them have invalid signatures in them.  I have been unable to find a way to detect which have invalid signatures short of manually opening up all of them and taking notes.

I have been tinkering with the Microsoft.Office.Interop.InfoPath library, but the signature objects that are exposed do not seem have a property for whether or not they are valid.

Has anyone else experienced this and found a solution?
Thanks in advance!